# Connect to BTLE device using 32feet.net using unique service protocol

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth, 32feet, btle

I have a bluetooth low energy (BTLE) device, which I need to connect to my PC. To do so, I use the windows API reference in a desktop WPF app.

The bluetooth device is rather simple: 1 service, 2 characteristics (one read/notify, one to write to).

```
To make below code work, add the following references to the WPF (for windows 10):
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd
```

Windows API code for C#

```
public GattDeviceService BLEService;
public GattCharacteristic BLEData_ReadNotify;
public GattCharacteristic BLEData_Write;
private static readonly Guid Guid_service = new Guid("25FB9E91-1616-448D-B5A3-F70A64BDA73A");
public static readonly Guid Characteristics_ReadNotify = new Guid("C3FBC9E2-676B-9FB5-3749-2F471DCF07B2");
public static readonly Guid Characteristics_Write = new Guid("D6AF9B3C-FE92-1CB2-F74B-7AFB7DE57E6D");


// Find all BTLE devices that have the service Guid: Guid_service
public void findandconnect() { 
    var BTLEdeviceList = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(Guid_service));
    // lets assume at least one device is found, store it's id.
    id = BTLEdeviceList[0].id;

    // Connect to the SERVICE of the device
    BLEService = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(id);

    // Get the first "ReadNotify" characteristics of that service
    BLEData_ReadNotify = BLEService.GetCharacteristics(Characteristics_ReadNotify).First();
    // If that value changes, update an event
    BLEData_ReadNotify.ValueChanged += BLEData_ValueChanged;

    // Also get the first "write" characteristics of that service
    BLEData_Write = BLEService.GetCharacteristics(Characteristics_Write).First();
    // and tell that characteristics to NOTIFY me if the BTLE device has an update.
    await BLEData_ReadNotify.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
    // Successfully connected

    // Send the command "RUN\r" to the write characteristics, to let it start to execute the program
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RUN" + "\r");
    IBuffer ibuffer = buffer.AsBuffer();
    // Sending "RUN"
    await BLEData_Write.WriteValueAsync(ibuffer);
}
// And here should be some event function for the ValueChanged
```

Well, it works, kinda... It is unstable as hell, most of the time it generates errors that can't be solved:

Line: BLEData_ReadNotify.WriteClientCharacteri... produces
*There is no user session key for the specified logon session. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070572)*

and *The semaphore timeout period has expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070079)*. This second error is less common and appears when the script first does not receive anything, then via a timer it tries to send the RUN command again, then all crashed and the error apears.

Searching on stackoverflow and many sites, I found that both above errors are impossible to solve. Hence my question:

**Can the above code be rewritten using 32Feet.net?**

In 2012 it was not possible [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304377/c-sharp-establishing-stream-from-laptop-internal-bluetooth-4-0-to-bluetooth-low/13438440#13438440) to use ble at all, but perhaps now it is? Using the scanning method in this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802791/pair-bluetooth-devices-to-a-computer-with-32feet-net-bluetooth-library), I CAN find my BLE device when it it NOT paired.

so, I tried some code

```
// mac is mac address of local bluetooth device
Guid Guid_service = new Guid("25FB9E91-1616-448D-B5A3-F70A64BDA73A");
localEndpoint = new BluetoothEndPoint(myRadio.LocalAddress, Guid_service);
// client is used to manage connections
localClient = new BluetoothClient(localEndpoint);

BluetoothAddress a = new BluetoothAddress(new byte[] { 180, 99, 76, 86, 31, 21 });
Guid Guid_service = new Guid("25FB9E91-1616-448D-B5A3-F70A64BDA73A");
localClient.Connect(a, Guid_service);

NetworkStream stream = localClient.GetStream();
```

but I am stranded at the line localClient.Connect with the error: 
*An exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred. 
Additional information: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond*

**Can the windows API code be rewritten in 32feet.net, ifso, how to proceed?**

*Note: I tried to connect to a BT2.1 device using windows native .net code, but the serial port is unstable and a pain in the head. With 32feet.net it now works splendidly over SerialPort, very stable and it connect each time!*

Comment: Any solution you got it for this? I am also looking for the same.

Comment: The solution is to use windows 8+, and make use of the winRT API. Search for something like "how to include winRT in desktop C# application". Once you have included the WinRT API, you can make use of its bluetooth calls, which allows you to connect to BT 2.1 as well as BT4 devices. I have code laying around somewhere, but have no time right now. Comment if you need code and i'll post it asap.

Comment: Yeah man please post the code or link which ever is possible for you. Thanks.

Comment: any luck finding that code? I tried the way have said but I am getting `FileNotFound` error in `await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(device.Id)`

Comment: I have two iOS devices communicating flawlessly but when I try the above code (windows 10 laptop to an iOS device), I always get 0 devices in the device list.

Answer (score 0):

I had simular issue with this relating to

the semaphore timeout period has expired. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070079).

My issue was resolved with .net 4.7.1. Also I needed to make sure I had the latest microsoft bluetooth driver for the bluetooth device i was using

SerialPort streams no longer terminate the process when exceptions occur on the background thread. This can happen when removing a USB serial port while in use. This new behavior is controlled by the Switch.System.IO.Ports.DoNotCatchSerialStreamThreadExceptions AppContext switch. This switch is set to truetf get by default when targeting .NET 4.7 or below. [428461, System.dll, Bug]

https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/0745983093568027ff931672d9db021e3e120b5b/releases/net471/dotnet471-changes.md

Update: Actually it appears to be 2 issues in one. .net bug and a firmware issue where the device was never turning back on the bluetooth module.